# Building Wix project in TeamCity and send to Octopus have problem with GetAssem

Tags: deployment, wix, teamcity, octopus

```
     error MSB4018: The "GetAssemblyVersionInfo" task failed unexpectedly.
 error MSB4018: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'Web.Client.Installer.exe' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.
    File name: 'Web.Client.Installer.exe' ---> System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'Web.Client.Installer.exe' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.
    File name: 'Web.Client.Installer.exe'
      
       at System.Reflection.AssemblyName.nGetFileInformation(String s)
       at System.Reflection.AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(String assemblyFile)
       at OctoPack.Tasks.GetAssemblyVersionInfo.UseAssemblyVersion(FileVersionInfo info) in C:\buildAgent\work\43311e7383a06d57\source\OctoPack.Tasks\GetAssemblyVersionInfo.cs:line 84
       at OctoPack.Tasks.GetAssemblyVersionInfo.CreateTaskItemFromFileVersionInfo(String path) in C:\buildAgent\work\43311e7383a06d57\source\OctoPack.Tasks\GetAssemblyVersionInfo.cs:line 62
       at OctoPack.Tasks.GetAssemblyVersionInfo.Execute() in C:\buildAgent\work\43311e7383a06d57\source\OctoPack.Tasks\GetAssemblyVersionInfo.cs:line 39
       at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecuti
```

I have to 2 build steps and the first step is .net build. It build fine and no problem. In the second step, the error displayed above. Both configurations is similar. Only differences are:

> /p:RunWixToolsOutOfProc=true  /p:RunOctoPack=true
> /p:OctoPackPublishPackageToHttp=http://server/nuget/packages?replace=true
> /p:OctoPackPublishApiKey=some_key

Understand it couldn't find the exe file but how do I tell teamcity to find this file

Comment: It doesn't look like the file could not be found. This exception is thrown in a number of cases: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.badimageformatexception?view=net-5.0#remarks. Is it possible that Web.Client.Installer.exe is not a .NET assembly? Or, perhaps, it is loaded as 64-bit assembly but contains 32-bit features or resources? Anyway, I would suggest you step throw the possible reasons outlined in the article I reference, and check each if it could be the case.

Comment: I got it built but i need to append the /p:OctoPackPackageVersion=3.6.5 in teamcity build configuration under command parameters to work